# Static Signals in QT

Tags: c++, qt

Im looking for the elegant pattern to follow the events of all instances of a class. So in theory it should be possible to emit a signal as from the class either directly or within a static method (which doesn't seem to be necessary then) because:

The connect() method declares a sender and the signature of it. In this case it could be the class. There is no specific expectation to the sender. As far as I understood, the signal itself is an object on the event stack, oriented to the sender. It shouldn't matter where is was generated(in a static or non static context/method).

So in general: what might be the issue with declaring the signal a static function other that expect the object signalling it is a valid Instance of the class.

It is already possible now through a helper-instance (e.g. the first instance) of the same class (referable through a static public pointer within the class) or for clarification of a specific helper class instance. Then one has to connect to that static pointer and through that, listen to all of them. Every Instance has then indirectly emit through it by

```
helperInstance->staticEmit(signalFoo,this);
```

So the question is: is there a more direct/elegant way or should QT look into this?

Comment: It's not clear to me from your question if you have actually tried declaring a signal to be static or not?

Comment: Great Point, actually haven't tried it, but as expected in the moc:
error: ‘this’ is unavailable for static member functions
 QMetaObject::activate(this, &staticMetaObject, 0, _a);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, Qt Could implement this feature, by basically adding code generation for the helper object code you showed  to the moc compiler.

Because any signal is a function declaration, of which the implementation is generated by the moc compiler. This implementation is basically just a:

```
for( auto& slot: connected_slots):
    slot.object->slot.function()
```

(very simplified)

this `connected_slots` needs to live somewhere. ie. it is a variable, which needs to be stored in memory.
So in any case you are going to need an object of some kind to store this in. This is normally in the `QObject` base class.

My guess for the reason that they didn't add this, is because the Qt framework is very object oriented, and the added complexity outweighs the benefits.

Comment: Thanks for the clearance, I've expected something like this. And the "needs to live somewhere" aspect was bothering me. The strong OO design is actually one of the best parts in the QT Framework, but once I've got into implementation details in Java, I can't get rid of the concept of a the class object, representing the class itself. Having namespaces in c++ keeping together all static props of a class is somewhat of a first step towards that.

Comment: Well, apart from whether OO is a good thing, Qt is OO, and static functions not so much. So it doesn' t really fit. Isn't the point of a class object to represent the class? or do you mean there is a metaobject baked into java classes? (it's a long time ago for me )

Comment: Yes, there is the .Class reference for all Objects, helpful with reflextions. And for the VM the static props and methods need to live somewhere. I Believe static props and methods could be very much in line with OO but what we most often see are patterns of avoiding OO when using statics, so I guess there it comes from. I will stick with the first instance approach. But since this is so easy possible I believe I should be made possible to declare signals static.